# Maclaurin expansions

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis, limits

> Let $f(z)=\sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j}$  be the Maclaurin expansion of
>   a function $f(z)$ analytic at the origin. Prove each of the following:
>
> a.) $\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}a_jz^{2j}$ is the Maclaurin expansion of
>   $g(z):=f(z^2)$.
>
> b.) $\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}a_jz^{m+j}$ is the Maclaurin expansion of
>   $h(z):=z^mf(z)$.
>
> c.) $\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}a_j(z-z_0)^j$ is the Taylor expansion of
>   $g(z):=f(z-z_0)$ around $z_0$.

For a, I got:

$$g(z)=\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\frac{g^n(0)}{n!}z^n=\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}\frac{g^{2j}(0)}{(2j)!}z^{2j}=\sum^{\infty}_{j=0}a_jz^{2j}$$

but I do not know how to do b nor c because it will involve a different process than a correct?

Comment: I have no idea what you did for a) above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Maclaurin/Taylor expansion  is unique.

$g(z) = f(z^2) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j(z^2)^{j} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{2j}$.

$h(z) = z^m f(z) = z^m \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j} = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_jz^{j+m}$

$g(z) = f(z-z_0) = \sum_{j=0}^{\infty}a_j(z-z_0)^{j}$

Comment: I havent learned yet that Taylor/Mac. expansion is unique, will it be absolutely necessary for me to know a different way of proving this other than uniqueness or will it be okay only to know that it is unique?

Comment: Well, it is easy to see it is unique by differentiating $n$ times, setting $z=0$ and looking at the value returned. The point is that you can use any appropriate technique to compute the expansion, it doesn't have to be via derivatives. For example, in the above, I just substituted $z^2$ for $z$ in the expansion of $f(z)$.

Comment: Alrighty then, I will save my self time by just using your technique. Thanks!